# multiple handling of scheduled jobs by kue in 'cluster' mode

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing, kue

I have set up kue to run with the [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module, which spawns a child process of `kue` for every CPU core available..

When the scheduler inserts the `every` keys to redis, everything seems to be in order - only a single keyset for every `every` run.

However, when the time to trigger the job processing comes, all child processes (workers) start handling the processing logic, which results in the job having multiple instances triggered from a single "scheduler" entry.

This symptom does not seem to happen when programmatically triggering a new job in `kue`, nor does it happen when using the `kue` API to do so.

Please advise.

**Main Bootstrap Code**

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    require('./init.js');

    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
    });

    require('./scheduler.js');
} else {
    require("./job_types");
}
```

**init.js**

```
/// Module Dependency
var cors = require('cors');
var kue = require('kue-scheduler');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./configs/config');
var redis = require("redis");

var client = redis.createClient();
var jobs = kue.createQueue();

require('./routes');

// Clearing redis for clean startup
console.log('Clearing old Redis data...');
client.flushall();

/// Webserver
var corsOptions = {origin: '*'};

var app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(kue.app);
app.listen(config.env.port, function () {
    var host = config.env.host;
    var port = config.env.port;

    console.log('[' + process.pid + '] Monitoring kue listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

// Handling safe shutdown
process.once('SIGTERM', function (sig) {
    kue.shutdown(5000, function (err) {
        console.log('[' + process.pid + '] Kue shutdown: ', err || '');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('[' + process.pid + '] ' + err);
    console.log('[' + process.pid + '] ' + err.stack);
});
```

**scheduler.js**

```
var scheduler = require('kue-scheduler');
var q = scheduler.createQueue();

// Set specific job scheduling here
q.every('1 minutes', q.createJob('getSocialEntities').attempts(3).priority('normal'));

// General scheduler event handling
// Uncomment for debug
q.on('already scheduled', function (job) {
    console.log('[' + process.pid + '] job is already scheduled: ' + job.type + ' (' + job.id + ')');
});

q.on('schedule success', function (job) {
    console.log('[' + process.pid + '] job scheduled: ' + job.type + ' (' + job.id + ')');
});

q.on('schedule error', function (error) {
    console.error('[' + process.pid + '] failed scheduling job');
    console.error(error);
});
```

- **job_types** - contains the kue `jobs.process('job type',...)` methods to handle all the job logic itself.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?